# Different scrollbar types on different computers

Tags: css

I'm having alignment issues due to the fact that on some machines the scrollbar is a permanent fixture on a div (which affects the flow of the content and pushes it to the left), and on others the scrollbar only appears when you scroll and it doesn't affect the content flow. The strange part is that is that the two machines I'm comparing are both extremely similar in that they are running the same OS, same version of Chrome etc. Why is it different across different machines?

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing the question I figured out how to make it the same across the board, although not why two machines running the same software produce different results.

Using `overflow-y: overlay` forces the second type of behaviour I described in my question, where the scrollbar doesn't affect the flow of the content. This is arguably the best behaviour in most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same issue.
In my case the root cause was in the setting  "Show scroll bars: Always". It is the MacOS setting: System Preference -> General -> Show scroll bars